# Tomcat 6.0.37 not processing jstl tag statements

Tags: jstl

I have a simple test page with the following statement but it appears that the ${} tags are not being processed by Tomcat and i get no errors in the log.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSTL Test Example</title>
<body>
Setting value using c:out <c:set var="name" scope="request" value="Testing" /><br>
Value is: <b><c:out value="${name}"/></b><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Browser Output:
Setting value using c:out 
Value is: ${name}

Using the information from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info
I verified 
1) Tomcat lib has jstl.2 jar , there are no duplicate jars - if i remove this jar i get a big exception complaining about missing tag classes.
2) My webapp does not have jstl jar in the classpath.
3) Tomcat web.xml  has the correct servlet specification

```
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"                   
version="2.5">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I was missing the servlet 2.5 declaration. It is working now. Sorry for the confusion. The stack overflow info link on jstl confirmed this  upon checking again.

Comment: Post your comment as answer and mark it with the green check in two days.

Answer (score 0):

their may be conflict of jsp-api jar

remove jstl.version.jar from tomcat lib

and add directly dependency in your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and try !